# How can i wipe a corrupt git folder but save all .gitignored files and directories

Tags: git, github, gitlab, version-control

My project seems hopelessly corrupted - I can start with no changes (according to git status), make a one-line change to a single file, confirm via `git status` that it's the only changed file, add it and commit, and then see via `git show` that the commit includes changes to unrelated files from other branches, and also deleted files that I haven't touched in months.  I've tried removing `.git/index` and `git reset` but that only solves the problem temporarily.  I think complex operations like `cherry-pick` trigger it but am not sure.

So, is there a way to totally wipe any metadata or object storage that'd be causing this?  Ideally I'd like to clone from the github repo, but keep any ignored files (of which there are many).

I'm using git 2.24 on Mac OS X 10.15

Edit - here is an example git session.  `gst` = `git status.` Why is the pem file deleted?

```
Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ gst
On branch mm_worker_fail
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    config.py

Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ rm config.py
Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ gst
On branch mm_worker_fail
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    config.py

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    config.py

Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ git add config.py
Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ gst
On branch mm_worker_fail
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    config.py
    deleted:    some-file.pem

Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at 6999af1 update tables
Alex-MacBook-Pro:heroku-backend alex$ gst
On branch mm_worker_fail
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    config.py
```

Comment: If you clone, you get an exact replica of the repo at GitHub. To "wipe" any "metadata", delete the full `.git` directory (you will lose ALL history and all commits). `.gitignore` is only a file, it is not metadata – it is tracked like any other file in your working tree

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the _text_ output of your `git status` output

Comment: Are you by any chance on Windows or MacOS, and the file `config.py` is actually not named exactly like that but with some letters in uppercase, like `Config.py`? Does the repository contain several versions of `config.py` with different casing? Show the repository contents: `git show HEAD:` (note the trailing `:`).

Comment: @j6t I am on Mac OS X, but there are no other similarly named files

Comment: Is this folder synchronized to the Cloud?

Comment: no, it's not synchronized

Comment: Yes, case-sensitivity problems sound could be a likely cause.

Comment: No, it's not the problem

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I feel to suggest you is:

```bash
cd <CORRUPTED_PROJECT_FOLDER>
mv .git .git.old

cd ..
git clone <REPOSITORY_URL> <PROJECT>.tmp

cd ../<CORRUPTED_PROJECT_FOLDER>
mv ../<PROJECT>.tmp/.git .
rm -rf ../<PROJECT>.tmp

# Do any operation: add, commit, push...

rm -rf .git.old
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by upgrading git to 2.33.0 and then deleting and recreating .git/index.  I verified that deleting/recreating .git/index on its own was not sufficient.